# Calculate θ and ø angles between origin and x,y,z coordinate

Tags: javascript, math, 3d

I'm using [three.js](http://threejs.org/) for a small 3D POC project. The following snippet  calculates the new x,y,z position for a 3D object in orbit around the origin (0,0,0):

```
x = rho * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
y = rho * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
z = rho * Math.cos(phi);
```

In the above example, *theta* and *phi* are known and used to calculate the new x,y,z coordinate for the orbiting 3D subject.

The above works well, but I also want to do the inverse.

How do I go about calculating *theta* and *phi*, if I only have an x,y,z point, this all in relation to the origin point (0,0,0)?

Comment: just rearrange the equations. inverse of sin is asin. inverse of cos is acos

Comment: Thanks @GarrGodfrey I was thinking about that, but not sure if I'm doing it 100% right. Am I correct saying that z = rho * Math.cos(phi); then becomes Math.acos(z / rho); and the same for the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC

```
r = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
θ = Math.acos(z/r);
φ = Math.atan2(y, x);

x = r * Math.sin(θ) * Math.cos(φ);
y = r * Math.sin(θ) * Math.sin(φ);
z = r * Math.cos(θ);
```

You seem to have your `θ` and `φ` swapped the other way around (which is just a notation choice)